# gcc internal error when using variadic concept template

Tags: c++, gcc

I recently played around with the concepts feature in `gcc` and stumbled upon this error when using variadic concept templates in the constructor or member function of a class:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
concept bool ConvertibleNoNarrow = requires(From f, To t) {
    t = { f };
};

class Foo
{
public:
    template<ConvertibleNoNarrow<double>... Args>
    Foo(Args&&... args) { /*...*/ }
};
```

When using `Foo`, gcc shows an internal error:

> ```
> err.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class ... Args>  requires  ConvertibleNoNarrow<Args, double>... Foo::Foo(Args&& ...) [with Args = {double}]’:
> err.cpp:23:11:   required from here
> err.cpp:13:3: internal compiler error: in tsubst_constraint, at cp/constraint.cc:1956
>    Foo(Args&&... args) { }
>    ^~~
> ```

If the same signature is used in a global function, everything works as expected:

```
/* works */    
template<ConvertibleNoNarrow<double>... Args>
void Test(Args&&... args) { }
```

Can anyone reproduce this or has a clue why this happens and how an existing bug report might be called?

**EDIT:**

My gcc version:

> ```
> gcc (Gentoo 7.2.0 p1.1) 7.2.0
> Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
> ```

Comment: Seems to be [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79917)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in gcc ([bugzilla link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79917)).

Nevertheless you can workaround the problem by adding the constraint in a `requires` clause. Therefore we check the concept on every type and return `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` accordingly. By doing this, we can use `std::conjunction_v` together with parameter pack expansion to constraint each type independently.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
        requires std::conjunction_v<std::conditional_t
            < ConvertibleNoNarrow<Args, double>
            , std::true_type
            , std::false_type
            >...>
    Foo(Args&&... args) { /*...*/ }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @nyronium's answer, but a little simpler, you can use a fold expression in the requires clause.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
        requires (ConvertibleNoNarrow<Args, double> && ...)
    Foo(Args&&... args) { /*...*/ }
};
```

I tested the equivalent on GCC 7.3.0.